# Promo Graphic в Google Play

Tags: java, android, google-play

Зачем нужен Promo Graphic? Я прочитала, что его используют для продвижении приложения на более поздних версиях Android OS, ниже 4.0, стоит ли вообще загружать это изображение? Я имею ввиду, что сегодня все меньше и меньше пользователей пользуются Android ниже 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promo Graphic относится к графическим ассетам, которые помогают продвигать и рекламировать ваше приложение на рынке Андройд приложений (Android Market), относится к определенным категориям приложений. Сами разработчики рекомендуют использование данного ресурса. Ежели не хотите использовать данную возможность, то в консоли разработчика(Developer Console) можно установить запрет на продвижение такого типа. Но резонный вопрос - зачем? Продвижение на то и продвижение, чтобы воспользоваться всеми доступными способами для привлечения внимания пользователя.